# search for name pattern in a dataset

Tags: r

I have minimized my problem to a dataset (df_sum) that consists only of characters, like this

```
"LPC(20:1) uM"         "LPE(16:0) uM"         "LPE(16:1) uM"         "LPE(18:0) uM"         "LPE(18:1) uM"         "PA(32:1) uM"          "PA(34:1) uM"         
"PA(36:1) uM"          "PS(34:1) uM"          "PS(36:1) uM"          "PG(34:1) uM"          "PG(36:1) uM"          "PE(28:0) uM"          "PE(30:1) uM"
"LPC(20:1)"         "LPE(16:0)"         "LPE(16:1)"         "LPE(18:0)"         "LPE(18:1)"         "PA(32:1)"          "PA(34:1)"         
"PS(36:1)"          "PG(34:1)"
```

As you can see, some values are the same but with an extra tag "uM" at the end.

My goal is to find which values are unique and actually the same without removing the uM tag (thing that i tried, like this `df_sum <- sub(" uM", "", df_sum)`)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what would the final solution look like? Could you just store the unique values into a separate object? I.e `x <- unique(gsub('\\suM$', '', df_sum))` or does it need to be embedded in the data.frame in some form?

Comment: Or `table(sub(" uM", "", df_sum))` if the number of repeats matters

Comment: @D.sen, @prosoitos I figured it out based on your answers. My final solution would be one that I could be able to identify which values were unique or not, like a frequency table that @prosoitos proposed (with a small addition) `data.frame(table(sub(" uM", "", df_sum)))`.

Comment: the only thing that i can't figure out is whether or not the unique value, in the req table, had the "uM" tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've done it. Here's the code I used:

```
names.um <- names(df_sum[,names(dplyr::select(df_sum, dplyr::contains("uM")))]) #select 'uM' names from joint dataset 
names.um <- sub(" uM", "", names.um )#remove the 'uM' tag 

names.filou <- names(df_sum[,names(dplyr::select(df_sum, dplyr::ends_with(")")))])#select 'Filou' names from joint dataset 

pos.filou <- which(!names.filou %in% names.um)#(1)find possitions where values from 'Filou' don't match the ones from 'uM'
pos.um <- which(!names.um %in% names.filou)#(2)find possitions where values from 'uM' don't match the ones from 'Filou'


names.filou[pos.filou]#show values from (1)
names.um[pos.um]#show values from (2)
```